# What is the best way to show a submenu in a tile menu design like Windows?

Tags: usability, menu, windows-os, tiles

Recently, I designed a tiles menu and it is responsive, which means it will support desktop, tablet/iPad, and mobile devices.
But I notice it is very hard to have a submenu in it. Can anyone please provide me some ideas for the best way to show the submenu in a tiles menu like Windows 10?

Here is the layout; the top left tile is the logo.

[image]

I have tried a slide menu, but it doesn't provide me the best solution. Because if I clicked at the bottom left tile, it will be a bit weird when the slide menu slides in from the right edge. The second reason is, there is a big gap: the user has to move their mouse from left to right edge and select the options. Also, because of the big gap issue, it makes the button and the active submenu lose their connection.

[image]

Comment: Does the Windows 10 style guide say anything about submenus?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let me make it clear, the fact that the placement of the menu needs to be mainly dictated by its contents.
If you place the main CTA's such as "Upgrade plan" or "settings", it'd have to be placed in a more apparent manner.
To answer this question, I'm gonna assume that this sub menu will affect the global app settings and not the particular page alone and that there is only one menu, globally that does these controls.

So if I was you, I wouldn't have a settings tile.
Tiles in the Metro UI are usually used to hold either widgets (weather, finance, etc) or links to apps (Desktop, IE, etc).
Having a settings tile is not the best approach as you'd ideally want to separate the content from the controls. Moreover, since the tile dimensions are not consistent, you'd find the settings tile to be placed in different places across different apps (and even devices).

So I'd recommend triggering a menu on click of a gear icon or a 3-dot submenu icon (if the options are more like the traditional right click menu item equivalent).
You can stick this icon to the top bar so that it is always visible.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt idea.What I mean is when you visit the homepage, it's a tile design layout with menu items. How can I show a submenu at one of the blocks? E.g. Menu -> submenu 01, submenu 02, submenu 03

Comment: So you mean to say each tile triggers a separate sub-menu?

Comment: Yes. But some of the tiles might just an images.

Comment: That, by the way @JeffreyLeong will get tedious quickly. Especially when you have a lot of tiles.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use UI similar to [Tile Folders](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-tile-folders-on-start-menu-in-windows-10/) but I do not think that any [control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/index) or even guidelines out of the box to help you with that.

Here is how it looks in Windows

[image]